# Upgrade 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 advice

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, ce-1.9.3.0

I am looking to upgrade from 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 and from what I read I can see everyone suggests you basically start a new fresh project with 1.9.3 and then copy in the extensions. However the bit that I can't see how to do how to copy all the catalog and other data such as customers

Is the correct way of going about it or is there a better way? EG perhaps just using /downloader and upgrading all modules to 1.9.3?

Comment: Related question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/125094/2380

Comment: I agree its related but its does't unfortunately fully answer my question relating to transferring data from the old 1.9.2.4 project to 1.9.3 project if I start a fresh project. The answer (which hasn't been accepted)  suggests the best way would perhaps be to completely over write the core files, but this is not what Magento recommends.

Comment: Agreed with you that's why the answer didn't get upvoted I reckon ^^

Comment: I am also further confused as I cant seem to download 1.9.3 from Magento as I cant find a link. There only seems to be a link for 1.9.1

Comment: Got to this page: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download then click the Release Archives tab, go to the 8th section called "ver 1.9.x" and it'll be there ;)

Comment: Ah great thanks so just not to figure out the best way / exactly how to upgrade

Comment: Hi @Goose84, did you have any luck with this? I am in the same situation and just overriding the files did not work for me...thanks!

Comment: No I haven't tried yet and saw 1.9.3.1 is now out also

Comment: Did you read this detailed blog https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 5):

1. Magento Compilation from System > Tools > Compilation > Disable and Magento Cache from System > Cache Management > Select All > Action: Disable > Submit
2. Now remove all files and folders from your previous Magento directory (make sure to keep your backup in a safe place) and place all files and folders from Magento 1.9.3 package.
3. Launch web browser, go to your link. You will be asked to install fresh Magento v1.9.3 store but don’t worry, keep going and when you will reach to the Configuration page. Fill it up with the same information you used for your previous Magento store which includes SQL DB Server Hostname, SQL DB Name, SQL Server Username, SQL Server Password, Base URL and Admin Path.
4. Once the installation is finished, do not visit frontend or backend page. From your Magento v1.7 files and folders backup, copy and merge following files and folders into your new Magento v1.9.x store directory:

   - Community Folder: ROOT > app > code > community
   - Local Folder: ROOT > app > code > local
   - Media Folder in Root Directory: ROOT > media
   - Your Theme Folder: ROOT > app > design > frontend > default (package name) > “your_theme” (If you are using “default” package for your theme then just copy theme folder otherwise you need to copy the whole package which includes your theme folder)
   - Skin Folder in Root Directory: ROOT > skin
   - Module’s Custom XML Files: ROOT > app > etc > modules > “your_custom_XML_files”
   - Admin Theme Folder: ROOT > app > design > adminhtml > default
   - Custom JS Folder: ROOT > app > js
   - Now finally delete everything from ROOT > var > cache and from ROOT >
     var > sessions to clear all sessions and cache.

Answer (score 1):

Login to magento admin and Go to System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager and login with your admin credentials

Now Follow below screen shots :

[image]

[image]

Comment: This goes against what the Offical Magento docs say though?

Comment: Sure @Goose84? http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/magento-connect-update-magento.html

Comment: What is see is "Note: You currently cannot upgrade to this version using Magento Connect Manager. We expect to resolve this issue soon." in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1931

Comment: I did "Mage_All_Latest" and only half of it was updated, did the second update manually selecting every module that was not updated and it worked.