# upgrading from version 1.9.2.3 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

If I update the files

1. How much **time** it will take to **upgrade**?
2. Which **files** I need to **backup**?
3. Is it any **manual way** to upgrade or just **clicking on upgrade** and it will do **automatic**?

I am new in Magento. Early response is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

1) It is depends on internet and server connection.

2) For safety purposes you need to take backups of the entire database and file & directory structure apart from the /var folder.

3) Magento provides instructions for upgrade of the magento.com web site.

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/magento-connect-update-magento.html

also  check  this link :)
[Upgrade 1.9.2.4 to 1.9.3 advice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140838/upgrade-1-9-2-4-to-1-9-3-advice)