# How to update to 1.9.3.1 on a production system?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

In the [release-notes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1931) they say

> You currently cannot upgrade to this version using Magento Connect Manager. We expect to resolve this issue soon.

How am I supposed to update my production system, which runs on 1.9.2.4?

I tried replacing `core` and `community` directories in the app folder. But that resulted in an error.

Comment: Side note: as I pointed out here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/125094/2380 Magento no longer recommends using the Magento Connect Manager to upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yikes.

Don't update a production site directly in production.
You WILL have a production site that is broken and endless days of stress that is totally avoidable.

Do it right.

Get a dev site up. Upgrade there. Test every aspect of your site after the upgrade.

You WILL need to upgrade most 3rd party extensions.
You WILL need to re-integrate your custom templates.

Once you are done, you can deploy to production.

Upgrades are fairly complex. There is no magic GO button.

It is up to you how you setup the dev and test sites.
Using docker can make that easy, and not take a lot of your time.

https://github.com/ProxiBlue/vagrant-docker

For the upgrade itself, download the core magento package and drop that into the dev folder version of your site.

Clear cache. ( or better use n98-magerun to effect the upgrade scripts )

Good luck.

(Please, don't do it direct on production, or else we might just see you scream for help on a dead production site next)

Comment: ok. I'm not very experienced but I updated my dev system successfully. I got this project form someone else. It's a small project. What folders/files do I need to send to the production system now?

Comment: Everything. Best you first backup younlive db. Then make a copy of the folder the live code is on, just a simple file backup of current live code to another folder. Then send all fikes to replace all files from dev to live. Rsync is helpfull here as you can use it to sync with a --size-only switch. Meaning the bulk of the files that is still the same will not transfer over, making the send a lot faster.

Comment: Well. Exclude the media-folder or your product images might be missing

Comment: Good point. @seb

Comment: Highly recommend that you use GIT or SVN to manage the code. Pushing changes from your dev to production is usually as simple as a SSH command to pull in the update code. Even if you don't use GIT on the production code, using a tool such as SourceTree to track your dev code really helps identify which code has been pushed to the server and which hasn't. (EX: login with FTP... copy a modified or new file to production server, add file to GIT repo, commit)